# how can i create a list from lager list and only 3 number position in to new list in Python

Tags: python

how can i create a list from lager list and only 3 number position in to new list in Python

```
list = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
```

Can it be like this?

```
list = (1,5,9,12,15,18,21)
```

Comment: First, do not overwrite the built-in `list` function, Second `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)` is not a list.

Comment: Do you mean take every third item? Then why isn't the output `[1,4,7,10...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `slicing`:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
list1[::4]
```

```
>>> [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21]
```

also don't use *list* as a list name

Comment: This returns [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21] not 12, 15, 18

Comment: @Sayse yes and according to his explanation, that's what he wants despite the desired output looks different

Comment: thanks you bro :D

Comment: @PhanSteel no prblemo ;)